# New log file whenever I start Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

I am getting overwhelmed with the log information in Karaf logs especially when they belong to previous runs. Is there a way to have a new log file for each time I start Karaf?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the configuration for logging in the org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg in the etc folder. 
Change your appenders to the way you want it to behave, for example a dailyrolingfileappender if configured correct like for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269999/how-do-i-make-log4j-clear-a-log-at-startup). That should do it.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to rename the existing one and start new log file.

Comment: take a look at the std. log4j configuration, all of this can be applied to karaf