# Manually clear log4j log file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've been able to find solutions to make the log file clear on each boot, but I don't want this to happen.

**I only want to clear my log4j log file when we explicitly choose to**, i.e. upon clicking a "clear log" button that calls an API to clear the log.

Is there a built-in log4j function to clear the log / how can I manually clear the log using Java code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/270026/2834978

Comment: I don't want it to clear the log when I restart the application. Only when I choose to by calling a function.

Comment: `cat /dev/null > /path/to/log`